# How to set PATH for all steps in Azure Pipeline Yaml?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-release-task

I want to define the `PATH` only once for the whole pipeline.

Is this possible?

I've done this, but it doesn't work:

```yaml
trigger:
  - master

jobs:
  - job: Application
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: "Install flutter"
        inputs:
          workingDirectory: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
          script: |
            git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable --depth 1
            export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=path;isOutput=true]$PATH"
            flutter config --no-analytics
            yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: "flutter get"
        inputs:
          script: |
            flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add the `BASH_ENV: "~/.profile"` variable and put path in `~/.profile`.

```yaml
trigger:
  - master

variables:
  BASH_ENV: "~/.profile"

jobs:
  - job: Application
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          workingDirectory: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
          script: |
            git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable --depth 1
            echo "export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin" >> ~/.profile
            source ~/.profile
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            flutter config --no-analytics
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is basically a Linux issue.

See the Ubuntu official document:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

> **Process locality:**
> The values of environment variables are local, which
> means they are specific to the running process in or for which they
> were set. This means that if we open two terminal windows (which means
> we have two separate bash processes running), and change a value of an
> environment variable in one of the windows, that change will not be
> seen by the shell in the other window or any other program currently
> on the desktop.

This is why the variable not been passed, it only lives in the first terminal.

Please check the system wide environment variables in the documents. I think you need to change something in the machine (edit some files or add some files).

Comment: This is partly true. You have to add a `BASH_ENV` variable in the YAML.